# Not able to use methods generated by ActiveRecord in resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, resque

In my current database setup I have a user and a server table.  I am able to do things like current_user.server from the rails console, but I am not able to do this from inside a resque worker.  I am however, able to call current_user.name because of this code in my resque worker:

```
current_user = User.find(current_id)
```

I was able to do this by passing in the current_user's id to the worker.  I thought I could use the same process for the user's server table; it's a has_one user->server relationship.

So I tried this:

```
current_server = Server.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
current_server[:cloudserver] = 123 #Just an example number
current_server.save
```

The first line worked fine, it returned the right server row. However, when I also include the second line I get an error:

```
TypeError can't convert Symbol into Integer
```

I know I created the cloudserver column as an integer type, and I made sure I loaded the rails environment in the resque workers.  I can set the correct number by using the rails console:

```
current_user.server[:cloudserver] = 123
current_user.save
```

Since I can set it outside of the resque worker, I'm pretty sure it's a resque problem.

Oh, and I'm also running rails 3.1rc4 if that helps.
Thanks all!

Comment: Figured it out! user.server.update_attribute(:cloudserver, 123) works perfectly!

Comment: Hope it can help someone